# problem with .install file

Tags: 6, installation

I tried to write the schema for a table as given below, but it did not work. let me know what is the mistake i have made.

```
<?php
/*** Implementation of hook_schema()*/
function sparsh_module_schema(){
    $schema['commissions_impt_data'] = array(
        'description' => 'Holds the imported data from different APIs like CJ and LinkShare for the sales done.',
        'fields' => array(
            'r_id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'description' => 'The record ID',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'disp-width' => '11'
            ),
            'member_id' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'description' => 'Member Id for the Record(User name)',
                'length' => '255',
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'member_type' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'description' => 'Member Plane Type',
                'length' => '255',
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'transs_date' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'Transaction Date',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'disp-width' => '11',
                'default' => 0
            ),
            'source' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'description' => 'Income Source',
                'length' => '50',
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'merchant' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'description' => 'Merchant Name',
                'length' => '50',
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'commission_income' => array(
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'Commission Income',
                'precision' => '10',
                'scale' => '2', 
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'sale_amt' => array(
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'Total Sale Amt.',
                'precision' => '10',
                'scale' => '2', 
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'user_comm_perc' => array(
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'User commission %',
                'precision' => '10',
                'scale' => '2', 
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'user_comm_amt' => array(
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'User commission amt',
                'precision' => '10',
                'scale' => '2', 
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'dat' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'description' => 'Serialized Array of Data for the record received from the API', 
                'serialize' => TRUE
            ),
            'st' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'description' => 'status of the record.',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'disp-width' => '11'
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('r_id'),
    );

    return $schema;
}
/**
* Implementation of hook_install().
*/
function sparsh_module_install(){
    drupal_install_schema('sparsh_module');
}
/**
* Implementation of hook_uninstall().
*/
function sparsh_module_uninstall(){
    drupal_uninstall_schema('sparsh_module');
}
//===============================================
//      Helper Functions
//===============================================

function sparsh_module_write_record($table, $object) {
  $schema = drupal_get_schema($table);

  $fields = $values = $placeholders = array();

  foreach ($schema['fields'] as $field => $info) {
    // For inserts, populate defaults from Schema if not already provided
    if (!isset($object->$field) && isset($info['default'])) {
      $object->$field = $info['default'];
    }

    // Build arrays for the fields, placeholders, and values in our query.
    if (isset($object->$field)) {
      $fields[] = $field;
      $placeholders[] = db_type_placeholder($info['type']);

      if (empty($info['serialize'])) {
        $values[] = $object->$field;
      }
      else {
        $values[] = serialize($object->$field);
      }
    }
  }

  $query = "INSERT INTO {". $table ."} (". implode(', ', $fields) .') VALUES ('. implode(', ', $placeholders) .')';
  return db_query($query, $values);
}
```

Comment: *What* does not work? Are there errors? "It does not work" is not a useful error description in any way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used two autoincrement columns in the schema (r_id & st); that is the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The `sparsh_module_write_record()` function you wrote seems a reduced version of [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6) that doesn't consider the case the row being written is already present in the database table.
If the code tries to save a row that uses the same value of the primary key used by another row, then you get an error.